# How do I match columns in two worksheet and if they match check if the second col has values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would appreciate any help with this. I have two worksheets with the following data

Worksheet 1

[image]

Worksheet 2

[image]

I am trying to match values in the name column in both worksheets and if the AGE column is NULL copy the name to a third worksheet. Example Age for Peter Tall and Steven Doe is NULL therefore those names should added to the third worksheet

Is this possible without a macro?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the following information is helpful.

First, you can use Filter function to find out the data from worksheet2 that name matches worksheet1. The formula of my sample is `=FILTER($D$2:$F$7,$D$2:$D$7=A2,"")`.

[image]

Then you can use Index + Match functions to find the Age is "0", the formula of my sample is `=IFERROR(INDEX($H$1:$H$6,SMALL(IF($I$2:$I$6=0,ROW($H$2:$H$6),4^8),ROW(A1)))&"","")`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you this was helpful.